# finding tags within a website and printing the corresponding quote

Tags: python, html, list

This is the website code:
I have to print all quotes with the tag 'inspirational'.
I know how to do it in theory but my code simply just isn't working. Could anyone help me?

I have been able to make two lists which contain all of the quotes and all of the tags. I am not sure how to count how many  within each  or how I would make each unique in that it would be able to assign these to each quote.

```
import requests 
import bs4


res = requests.get("http://quotes.toscrape.com/") 

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml') 
all_tags = []
all_quote = []
for element in div.find('a')['tag']:
    all_tags.append(element.text)
for element in soup.select('span'):
    all_quote.append(element.text)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Quotes to Scrape</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row header-box">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h1>
                    <a href="/" style="text-decoration: none">Quotes to Scrape</a>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>
                
                    <a href="/login">Login</a>
                
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">

    <div class="quote" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
        <span class="text" itemprop="text">“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”</span>
        <span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">Albert Einstein</small>
        <a href="/author/Albert-Einstein">(about)</a>
        </span>
        <div class="tags">
            Tags:
            <meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="change,deep-thoughts,thinking,world" /    > 
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/change/page/1/">change</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/deep-thoughts/page/1/">deep-thoughts</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/thinking/page/1/">thinking</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/world/page/1/">world</a>
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="quote" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
        <span class="text" itemprop="text">“It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.”</span>
        <span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">J.K. Rowling</small>
        <a href="/author/J-K-Rowling">(about)</a>
        </span>
        <div class="tags">
            Tags:
            <meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="abilities,choices" /    > 
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/abilities/page/1/">abilities</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/choices/page/1/">choices</a>
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="quote" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
        <span class="text" itemprop="text">“There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.”</span>
        <span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">Albert Einstein</small>
        <a href="/author/Albert-Einstein">(about)</a>
        </span>
        <div class="tags">
            Tags:
            <meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="inspirational,life,live,miracle,miracles" /    > 
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/inspirational/page/1/">inspirational</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/life/page/1/">life</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/live/page/1/">live</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/miracle/page/1/">miracle</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/miracles/page/1/">miracles</a>
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="quote" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
        <span class="text" itemprop="text">“The person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, must be intolerably stupid.”</span>
        <span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">Jane Austen</small>
        <a href="/author/Jane-Austen">(about)</a>
        </span>
        <div class="tags">
            Tags:
            <meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="aliteracy,books,classic,humor" /    > 
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/aliteracy/page/1/">aliteracy</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/books/page/1/">books</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/classic/page/1/">classic</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/humor/page/1/">humor</a>
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="quote" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
        <span class="text" itemprop="text">“Imperfection is beauty, madness is genius and it&#39;s better to be absolutely ridiculous than absolutely boring.”</span>
        <span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">Marilyn Monroe</small>
        <a href="/author/Marilyn-Monroe">(about)</a>
        </span>
        <div class="tags">
            Tags:
            <meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="be-yourself,inspirational" /    > 
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/be-yourself/page/1/">be-yourself</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/inspirational/page/1/">inspirational</a>
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="quote" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
        <span class="text" itemprop="text">“Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.”</span>
        <span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">Albert Einstein</small>
        <a href="/author/Albert-Einstein">(about)</a>
        </span>
        <div class="tags">
            Tags:
            <meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="adulthood,success,value" /    > 
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/adulthood/page/1/">adulthood</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/success/page/1/">success</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/value/page/1/">value</a>
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="quote" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
        <span class="text" itemprop="text">“It is better to be hated for what you are than to be loved for what you are not.”</span>
        <span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">André Gide</small>
        <a href="/author/Andre-Gide">(about)</a>
        </span>
        <div class="tags">
            Tags:
            <meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="life,love" /    > 
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/life/page/1/">life</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/love/page/1/">love</a>
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="quote" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
        <span class="text" itemprop="text">“I have not failed. I&#39;ve just found 10,000 ways that won&#39;t work.”</span>
        <span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">Thomas A. Edison</small>
        <a href="/author/Thomas-A-Edison">(about)</a>
        </span>
        <div class="tags">
            Tags:
            <meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="edison,failure,inspirational,paraphrased" /    > 
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/edison/page/1/">edison</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/failure/page/1/">failure</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/inspirational/page/1/">inspirational</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/paraphrased/page/1/">paraphrased</a>
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="quote" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
        <span class="text" itemprop="text">“A woman is like a tea bag; you never know how strong it is until it&#39;s in hot water.”</span>
        <span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">Eleanor Roosevelt</small>
        <a href="/author/Eleanor-Roosevelt">(about)</a>
        </span>
        <div class="tags">
            Tags:
            <meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="misattributed-eleanor-roosevelt" /    > 
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/misattributed-eleanor-roosevelt/page/1/">misattributed-eleanor-roosevelt</a>
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="quote" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
        <span class="text" itemprop="text">“A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.”</span>
        <span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">Steve Martin</small>
        <a href="/author/Steve-Martin">(about)</a>
        </span>
        <div class="tags">
            Tags:
            <meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="humor,obvious,simile" /    > 
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/humor/page/1/">humor</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/obvious/page/1/">obvious</a>
            
            <a class="tag" href="/tag/simile/page/1/">simile</a>
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav>
        <ul class="pager">
            
            
            <li class="next">
                <a href="/page/2/">Next <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a>
            </li>
            
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 tags-box">
        
            <h2>Top Ten tags</h2>
            
            <span class="tag-item">
            <a class="tag" style="font-size: 28px" href="/tag/love/">love</a>
            </span>
            
            <span class="tag-item">
            <a class="tag" style="font-size: 26px" href="/tag/inspirational/">inspirational</a>
            </span>
            
            <span class="tag-item">
            <a class="tag" style="font-size: 26px" href="/tag/life/">life</a>
            </span>
            
            <span class="tag-item">
            <a class="tag" style="font-size: 24px" href="/tag/humor/">humor</a>
            </span>
            
            <span class="tag-item">
            <a class="tag" style="font-size: 22px" href="/tag/books/">books</a>
            </span>
            
            <span class="tag-item">
            <a class="tag" style="font-size: 14px" href="/tag/reading/">reading</a>
            </span>
            
            <span class="tag-item">
            <a class="tag" style="font-size: 10px" href="/tag/friendship/">friendship</a>
            </span>
            
            <span class="tag-item">
            <a class="tag" style="font-size: 8px" href="/tag/friends/">friends</a>
            </span>
            
            <span class="tag-item">
            <a class="tag" style="font-size: 8px" href="/tag/truth/">truth</a>
            </span>
            
            <span class="tag-item">
            <a class="tag" style="font-size: 6px" href="/tag/simile/">simile</a>
            </span>
            
        
    </div>
</div>

    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted">
                Quotes by: <a href="https://www.goodreads.com/quotes">GoodReads.com</a>
            </p>
            <p class="copyright">
                Made with <span class='sh-red'>❤</span> by <a href="https://scrapinghub.com">Scrapinghub</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show your code? It will make it easier to see what you're doing wrong

Comment: just uploaded it, i was worried it would confuse things at first

Comment: If you click on ```inspirational``` tag, you can see all the quotes with that tag. Why not scrape data from that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken an empirical view of your HTML code and made some assumptions about its structure. I copied it to a file so, obviously, the file handling part of the code below won't be relevant to you. There are almost certainly more elegant ways to do this but I'm demonstrating a step-by-step approach which may (hopefully) make things clearer for you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


def isInspirational(div):
    if (d := div.find('div', class_='tags')):
        if (a := d.find_all('a', class_='tag')):
            for _a in a:
                if _a.text == 'inspirational':
                    return True


with open('/Users/andy/stack.html') as infile:
    soup = BS(infile.read(), 'html.parser')
    for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='quote'):
        if isInspirational(div) and (t := div.find('span', class_='text')):
            print(t.text)
```

The result will be:-

“There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.”
“Imperfection is beauty, madness is genius and it's better to be absolutely ridiculous than absolutely boring.”
“I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.”

Answer (score 0):

The webpage supports filtering quotes by the tags. You can click on inspirational tag and see all the quotes with that tag.

> `http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/inspirational/page/1/`

This would make your work easier.

Here is the code that prints all the quotes from the above URL.

```
import requests 
import bs4

res = requests.get("http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/inspirational/page/1/") 

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml') 
d = soup.findAll('div', class_='quote')
for i in d:
    print(i.find('span', class_='text').text.strip())
```